# How to write data from 1D array to an excel file from python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm new to python and I have to change this code to have a 1D array not a 2D array.This code is perfectly working to write data to an excel file. Please help me to change this in to a 1D array.

```
eg: only to enter as 1D array as below
  expenses = [
        [1000],
        [100],
        [300],
        [50],
    ]

import xlsxwriternter 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('20.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

expenses = [
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
]


row = 0
col = 0


for item,cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)

    row += 1



workbook.close()
```

Comment: I do not understand your question, you are incrementing `row` so it is placing the items in rows, if you instead incremented `col` it would write to separate columns...

Comment: No actually what I need is to pass data from a 1D array and print to an excel sheet. This is a sample example I found from a reference tutorial.https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html

Comment: so change it so that it works with the first `expenses` list? that would be easy, just change `for item,cost in (expenses):` to `for item, in (expenses):` so that you are unpacking only one item and not two.

Comment: I was trying to do that as you told but it throws this error -->TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'list'> in write()

Comment: you missed the trailing comma: `for item, in...` this means you are unpacking a single element from the list, either that or you do `for item in expenses:thing_to_write = item[0]`

Comment: Oh yeah it's working! Thank you soo much for your help! It means a lot! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question basically comes down to tuple unpacking, the for loop in the original code was basically doing this for each item in `expenses`:

```
item, cost = ['Rent', 1000] #unpacks 'Rent' to item and 1000 to cost
```

if each element of `expenses` consisted of only a single element you would unpack a single element with a trailing comma after the variable (like how you do with a single element tuple)

```
item, = [1000]  #unpacks 1000 to item
```

so in the for loop it would just be:

```
for item, in (expenses):
     #  ^ the trailing comma here!
```